# Copying a 2D String ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

This seems really trivial, but I'm having trouble copying a 2D String ArrayList into an entire new 2D String ArrayList data structure.

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copy(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> input) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copy = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> line = input.get(i);  // Issue here?
        for(int j = 0; j < input.get(i).size(); j++) {
            line.set(j, input.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

I'm not looking to make a shallow copy, I'm trying to iterate over an entire ArrayList and copy it into a new one. I feel like I'm not initializing the rows correctly with my line ArrayList, but I thought the whole point of the ArrayList data structure was that data could be added to it without initializing the size?

It appears the first line is being copied correctly, but I'm indexing out of bounds when I try to add a subsequent line.

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copy = new ArrayList<>(input);` ??

Comment: why are you having an inner for loop? I think you can just use
      for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
         copy.add(input.get(i));
      }

Comment: @Thuiya that won't copy the `ArrayList`, it's Java not C++.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wouldn't that just make a shallow copy?  Trying to create a whole new data structure in memory.

Comment: @JAL You're probably right, that's why it's a comment ;) - But wouldn't you be able to use the same tactic for child element?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Possibly, I'll have to test it out and see.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copy(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> input) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copy = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(input.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> line = input.get(i);
        copy.set(i, new ArrayList<String>(line.size())); // add internal array initialization
        for(int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {
            copy.get(i).set(j, line.get(j)); // actually copy value into new array
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Getting an out of bounds error on this line (same as the other solution): `copy.set(i, new ArrayList<String>(line.size()));`  Any idea why the strings are not being added to the ArrayList properly?

Comment: @JAL change `set(i` and `set(j` to `add(`

Answer (score 3):

You're forgetting to create the `ArrayList` inside the `ArrayList` itself.

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copy(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> input) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copy = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int j = 0; j < input.get(i).size(); j++) {
            line.add(input.get(i).get(j));
        }

        copy.add(line);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response.  Thanks!

Comment: Still getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0 on this line line.set(j, input.get(i).get(j)); Any idea what could be wrong? If I print the value input.get(i).get(j) I get a valid character, but it's not being added to the ArrayList properly